# How to add data and iterate Map of maps (Nested map) in Java?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

Using Java8/Collections/
I want to add data in Map in collections as:
`Map<String,Map<String,Double>> OuterMap=new LinkedHashMap<String,Map<String,Double>>();`

Inner map:

```
Map<String,Double> InnerMap=new LinkedHashMap<String,Double>();

OuterMap.put("Str1",InnerMap);
OuterMap.put("Str2",InnerMap);
```

The issue is I want to check the keys of InnerMap and it may vary to each other in InnerMap.

When I compare the keys of InnerMap. The OuterMap overrides the previous elements of the map.

I want the output like:
`Str1={"SNP1"=0.3,"SNP2"=0.56,"SNP3"="0.76"} , Str2={"SNP1"="0.16","SNP2"=0.56,"SNP3"=0.78,"SNP4"=.56}`

Comment: Don't use the same object as the value for multiple outer map keys?

Comment: As @Shawn says, or even more clearly, each inner map must be a brand new instance of LinkedHashMap, otherwise you're just referencing the same map everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating new map instances when storing the values.

The simplest way to create a copy of the map is to use [appropriate copy constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap-java.util.Map-):

```java
Map<String,Double> innerMap=new LinkedHashMap<>();

outerMap.put("Str1", innerMap);
outerMap.put("Str2", new LinkedHashMap<>(innerMap));
```

Please also make sure you adhere to Java naming conventions: `camelCase` for variables/fields/methods, `UpperCamelCase` for classes/interfaces/enums.